# How to integrate COM Interop (manipulations of Excel, Ms Word, etc) in a web-API written in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, api, com-interop

I am trying to integrate COM interop into my web API written in C#. And it seems that .net core of the web api cannot support COM technology.

Here's the error message I got:

```
FlicApi.Controllers.ButtonController.Post(string buttonId)
lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Is there any way to bypass this situation that COM is not supported on net-core for web API? Eventually what I want to achieve is call an API and do some manipulations on the Microsoft Excel.

Here's what I tried:

```
        // POST api/button/buttonId
        [HttpPost("{buttonId}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Post(string buttonId)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(value);

            //start Excel and get Application Object
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            //Add table headers going cell by cell.
            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Full Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Salary";

            oWB.SaveCopyAs(@"/Users/eaxz/Desktop/book1.xlsx");

            return "success";


        }
```

Comment: Since running Office apps in headless environment is not supported you'd be better off using some other libraries to achieve your goals... (which will also remove need for using COM interop)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Any other library recommendations? It seems COM is the way to go for c# though...

Comment: the way to go is to not use any office app in something running on a web server as IIS or every unattended environment without a "desktop". [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft.office.interop.word+server-side&oq=word+server+side&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.12537j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Microsoft explains why.
For Excel, I find NPOI very powerful and easy to use (much easier than using Office Object Model supplied with Excel). It's a .Net porting of the opensource Apache POI, for Java.

Comment: "ClosedXml" is also a great package for reading and writing Excel files.

Comment: `It seems COM is the way to go for c# though` never heard this before!

Answer (score 0):

COM Interop is not a good option for server side environment. You can try some third party component, for example, [GrapeCiy Document API](https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-excel)